# Equations in Latex

Tags: equations, matrices, alignment

I need to do: three equations (via the align* common environment) that will be aligned to the "=" sign and at least one equation within the text (so-called "inline" equations; hint: $). Include the use of indices, powers, roots, integrals, derivatives, and matrices. I tried doing this, but it doesnt work

```
\begin{equation}
 \label{eq1}
 \begin{split}
 $f(x) & = x^3+ \sqrt{x^3}$
 \begin{matrix}
 & = 1 & 0
 0 & 1
 \end{matrix}
 \end{split}
 \end{equation}
```

Comment: You should probably read an introduction about math in LaTeX. Remove that `$`'s inside `split`, you are already in math mode here.

Comment: Adding a sketch of the expected outcome would help

Comment: I think your homework is asking you to do two separate things: (1) an align environment with three equation, and (2) an inline equation.  Your attempt doesn't include an `align*`.

Comment: Have a look here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

See the definition of functions~$f$ and~$g$, as well as the matrix~$A$ below:
\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= a_1 x^2 + \sqrt{b x} - \int_0^4 c \, \mathrm{d}x \\
  g(x) &= \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \biggl( \dfrac{b_2^2}{x} \biggr) -
    \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial c} \\
      A &= \begin{pmatrix}
        i_{1,1} & j_{1,2} & k_{1,3} \\
        j_{2,1} & k_{2,2} & i_{2,3} \\
        k_{3,1} & i_{3,2} & j_{3,3}
     \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```